# Como guardar o ID do usuário logado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou usando em minha aplicação Windows Authentication. Tenho um controller onde o usuário deve cadastrar suas experiencias profissionais. Porém, da forma como foi feita a aplicação, eu preciso todas as vezes que for inserir um dado novo, colocar o número da matrícula ou ID dele. 
Como faço para resgatar ou guardar o Perfilid (matrícula) que a aplicação já pegou ao abrir o programa de modo que o usuário não precise digitar seu Perfilid toda vez que for inserir algo? É preciso criar uma sessão ou tem uma forma mais simples.

Minha view está assim:

```
@model Competências.Models.Experiencia

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/validation")

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions
                {
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    HttpMethod = "POST"
                }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

         <div class="col-md-4">
        <b>Id</b>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Perfilid, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Perfilid)
    </div>

    </div>

       <div class="modal-body row"> 
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Atividades)

        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Atividades, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Atividades)
    </div> </div>
```

Meu controller:

```
        public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }


    //// POST: /Experiencia/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Experiencia experiencia)
    {
        db.Experiencia.Add(experiencia);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Models:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Competências.Models
{
public class Experiencia
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "É obrigatório descrever as atividades desempenhadas na empresa")]
    [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "O campo atividades pode ter no máximo 255 caracteres")]
    public string Atividades { get; set; }

    public int Perfilid { get; set; }
    public virtual Perfil Perfil { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Na hora da sua autenticação crie um [Cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httpcookie%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ou [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httpcontext.session%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) para guardar esse valor de matricula. Logo abaixo as duas formas de criação.

Usando [Cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httpcookie%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): (são armazenados por usuário na sua máquina)

*Criando o Cookie*

```cs
if (Request.Cookies.Get("id_usuario") == null)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("id_usuario");
    cookie.Path = "/";
    // valor do usuário ou qual valor deseja guardar
    cookie.Value = "1"; 
    // tempo que ele expira está 10 minutos se pode colocar mais tempo. 
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10d);        
    // envia o cookie para HttpResponse, nesse momento ele criou e você pode utilizar nas diversas páginas.
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);                 
}
```

Recuperando o Cookie:

```cs
if (Request.Cookies.Get("id_usuario") != null)
{
    LblIdUsuario.Text = Request.Cookies.Get("id_usuario").Value;
}
```

---

Usando [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httpcontext.session%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): (são armazenados na memória no servidor, apesar que podem variar
pelas alternativas de estado de sessão)

*Criando Session*

```cs
if (Session["id_usuario"] == null)
{
    Session.Timeout = 10;
    Session.Add("id_usuario", "1");                
}
```

*Recuperando Session*

```cs
if (Session["id_usuario"] != null)
{
    LblIdUsuario.Text = (string)Session["id_usuario"];
}
```

---

***Obs:*** *Pode se criar rotinas de criptografia, para gravar essas informações.*

Comment: Certo. E essa sessão ou cookie eu crio dentro de um novo controller ou dentro do controller onde eu quero resgatar a informação, no caso, Experiencia?

Comment: Assim: Na hora que você autentica o usuário pelo windows no mesmo método do controller você usa o Criando Session ou Cookie. Agora para recuperar você vai no Controller que já existe entra no método e usa o Recuperando Session ou Cookie, entendeu @Victor

Comment: Entendi! Vou tentar aqui e qualquer coisa peço socorro de novo! hahaha Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Em que momento eu faço a atribuição do que eu peguei no session com o PK_Id que eu quero inserir?

Comment: @Victor no Criando Session, vejo o exemplo, e quando quiser recuperar esse valor é no Recuperando Session

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou usar o `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName, false);` ?

Assim você pode usar depois em qualquer lugar

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

para saber se está logado, e o

```
User.Identity.Name
```

Para saber o nome do usuário logado

No logout usar:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

Comment: Aqui, você pode usar o Id no lugar de UserName, ok ?